# Any difference between n % m and n - m * (n / m) expression in C++?

Tags: c++

As you've read in the title is there any difference between (n and m are two integer random variables)  n % m and n - m * (n / m) expression in C++? or they are equivalent and always give the same result? which one is recommended to use?
Thank you!

Comment: `n % m` is more clear even if the result is the same. Don't obfuscate your code for no reason. The compiler knows how to optimize your code better than you.

Comment: Signed or unsigned? Signed remainder acts funny with negative `m`

Comment: See e.g. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic#Multiplicative_operators, in particular the note about the sign of the operands before C++11.

Comment: Thank you everyone whe replied, i had unsigned integers in my mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In any programming languages you could achieve same results in many possible ways. This is guaranteed by maths which is implemented in programming language, based on math implemented on CPU. And mathematical methods are guaranteed to be correct by underlying theory.
But having the same result does not mean it is the same thing. Each operation is a processor command, which means processor time. See following code:

```
r = n % m;
r = n - m * (n / m);
```

And see the processor instructions. The first operation is exactly one processor mathematical instruction **idiv** and three **mov**es. The second one is three mathematical instructions **idiv+imul+sub** and two more **mov**es:
[image] 
Also involving many instructions means more complicated code, harder to get it correct. Think in terms of thousands of lines of code, function calls, loops, recursions.

Comment: I guess you have an unoptimized build. See e.g. https://godbolt.org/z/qSbAzZ

Comment: @Bob__ optimisation it is not something that compiler always can do, that's why it is irelevant in context of this question. Because not every situation can be optimised I especially did it volatile and unoptimised to show such situation.

Comment: @Bob__ the compiler can even skip everything and replace with compile time computed results, when it is possible, as optimisation.